# Obtener datos desde un controlador en Laravel en Vue Js y recorrerlos

Tags: vue.js

Estoy usando una variable sesión en el controlador y guardo los datos en un array la idea es mandarlos a `Vue` a través de `axios` y usarlos en Vue pero me da vació;

aquí recibo en Vue los datos

```
axios.get(url).then(function (response){
            var respuesta = response.data;
            this.productos = respuesta.productos.data;

        }).catch(function (error){
            console.log(error.response);
        })
```

y los asigno a la variable productos en el data e intento recorrerlo con `v-for` pero me sale vacío !

este es controlador :

```
 public function store(Request $request) {
    session_start();

   if (!isSet($_SESSION['data'])) 
       $_SESSION['data']= (object)array();

   if (isSet( $request->nombre )) {
      array_push( $_SESSION['data'], 
      (object)array(
        "nombre"=>$request->nombre,
        "id"=>$request->id ) );
    }

    $productos = json_encode( $_SESSION['data'] );

    return ['productos' => $productos];
```

Comment: Aunque el problema se resuelve con la respuesta de Gbianchi, la lógica del controlador no me queda clara,¿Qué intenta retornar? si lo que intenta retornar parecer ser solo un objeto, ¿Por qué un `v-for` ? además le recomiendo leer la [documentación](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/session) para manejar sesiones o almacenar datos en ellas _(disminuiría la cantidad de código (quizá) )_

Comment: Te explico, tengo poco tiempo usando laravel, y como estoy usando componentes de vue  la directiva v-for la uso para recorrer el array que intento recibir mediante axios!!

Comment: en cuanto a el controlador  se que no es la mejor alternativa para las sesiones pero como tengo poco conocimiento lo estaba intentado así y la idea general es mandar datos a través de axios desde mi componente y recibirlos en el controlador y posteriormente almacenarlos en esa sesión en un array, bueno todo hasta allí me resulta el problema esta cuando intento devolver los datos a vue para mostrarlos, aunque ya intente con lo que me comento gbianchi no tengo éxito! el array que recibo en el componente al parecer no se almacenan en el array que tengo definido en mi componente!

Comment: Estonces vamos a necesitar ver tu componente. Mi respuesta anda en cualquier componente de vue standard. Pero parece que el tuyo no es asi.

Comment: Y podes confirmar si realmente estas recibiendo algo o no?

Comment: Si estoy claro de eso, incluso cuando uso tu respuesta usando datos de una BD me resulta correctamente!! el problema creo que esta porque los datos que envió son de una variable de sesión... y lo que hago para verificar que los datos si están allí es revisar desde el navegador por la red y allí están

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tu problema es que `this`, no es `this` en ese contexto.

`This`, cuando estas dentro de una funcion, sufre el problema de que esta en otro contexto, y aunque existe, no es el mismo contexto de tu `this` de vue.

Para solucionar esto, solo tenes que asignar ese `this` antes de entrar a una variable que este en el entorno de esa función, y usar esa misma para asignar los valores.

Algo de este estilo:

```
var esta = this;
axios.get(url).then(function (response){
        var respuesta = response.data;
        esta.productos = respuesta.productos.data;

    }).catch(function (error){
        console.log(error.response);
    })
```

En esta, va a estar el puntero al this que vos queres.

Comment: O también las [Arrow Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Funciones/Arrow_functions) ;)

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta me aclaro dudas!!, aunque sigo sin tener éxito al recibir los datos